# Algorithm to calculate frequency and recency of an entity?

Tags: c#, algorithm, frequency, frequency-analysis

I have a list of entities opened by various users.
I keep track of each access of any entity by storing access dates and times as the following:

```
public class Entity
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<AccessInfo> Accesses { get; set; } 
    = new HashSet<AccessInfo>();
}

public class AccessInfo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public AccessInfoType Type { get; set; }
  public User User { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}

public enum AccessInfoType
{
  Create,
  Read,
  Update,
  Delete,
}
```

Now I'm trying to make an algorithm that filters the most wanted contacts based on both factors: recency and frequency.

I want contacts that were accessed 5 times yesterday to be prioritized over a contact that was accessed 30 times a week ago. But in the other hand, a user that was only accessed one time today is less important.

Is there an official name for this? I'm sure people have worked on a frequency calculation like this one before, and I'd like to read about this before I spend some time coding.

I thought about calculating the sum of the access dates in recent month and sort accordingly but I'm still not sure it's the right way, I'd love to learn from the experts.

```
return Entities
  .OrderBy(c =>
    c.Accesses
      .Where(a => a.Employee.UserName == UserName)
      .Where(a => a.DateTime > lastMonth)
      .Select(a => a.DateTime.Ticks)
      .Sum());
```

Comment: This is a good starting point I think http://www.evanmiller.org/rank-hotness-with-newtons-law-of-cooling.html

Comment: Take a look at the discussion here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions

Comment: @Francisco please post your link as answer. This is what I ended up using. It's indeed a great post. It's the `Math.Exp` function I was after...

Comment: Okay, will do. Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exponential decay is what you're looking for. See this link:

http://www.evanmiller.org/rank-hotness-with-newtons-law-of-cooling.html

Answer (score 1):

I would use a heuristic that assigns points to Entities for access and uses some kind of decay on those points.

For example, you could give an entity 1 point every time it is accessed, and once every day multiply all the points by a factor of 0.8

Comment: 1. That will require me to update all entities every day, which I don't want.  2. Your suggestion will work in a linear fashion which I want to avoid, because in the first period the decay rate is much higher.

Comment: 2. It's not linear. Decay with .8 every day implies exponential decay over time [0.8, 0.64, 0.51, 0.41, 0.38, ...]. 1. You could also compute it whenever someone visits, but that sounds a lot more expensive to me and also then you need to do calculations at a moment you don't want to. Maybe if you have a huge amount of entities and only a handful of visits it's worth it but I have a hard time imagining how.